# Algorithm for Triangle Tessellation of a Sphere

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I am trying to generate uniform points on a sphere using triangle tessellation where the vertices will be the points. What is a good algorithm to generate such tessellation. Below is picture to describe what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many software systems will do this directly.  Here's *Mathematica*:

```
Graphics3D[Point[SpherePoints[400]]]
```

[image: 400 sphere points]

```
HighlightMesh[DelaunayMesh[SpherePoints[400]], Style[1, Red]]
```

[image]